# Android 4.4.2: Problems with border-radius and box-shadow in combination with animations on some devices

Tags: android, css

I have created a small example on CodePen to demonstrate my situation: http://codepen.io/Trullus/pen/XKKmyV

As you can see, two of the containers have a rounded border:

```
border: 0.5em solid black;
border-radius: 5em;
```

The two other containers have a shadow:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 1em black;
```

Additionally a small animation is specified for the two containers with the class "failing".

Nothing too fancy and this seems to (and should) work just fine in every "modern" browser. But for some weird reason, the native browser on some (but for some reason not all) devices (e.g. my Galaxy Tab 4) with Android 4.4.2 has a problem rendering the elements with the animation. [This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W7ve.png) demonstrates, that the background overflows the border and the shadow of the containers. The elements without the animation are displayed perfectly fine.

```css
body {
  background: LightGray;
}

div {
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1.5em;
}

.working {
  background: DarkOliveGreen;
}

.failing {
  background: FireBrick ;
}

.border {
  border: 0.5em solid black;
  border-radius: 5em;
}

.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em black;
}

@-webkit-keyframes beat {
  0% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 ); }
  12.5% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1.3 ); }
  25% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 ); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 ); }
}

@keyframes beat {
  0% { transform: scale( 1 ); }
  12.5% { transform: scale( 1.3 ); }
  25% { transform: scale( 1 ); }
  100% { transform: scale( 1 ); }
}

.beat {
  -webkit-animation-name: beat;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  animation-name: beat;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="working border"></div>
<div class="failing border beat"></div>
<div class="working shadow"></div>
<div class="failing shadow beat"></div>
```

I have found several examples about problems with this CSS properties on Android 2.x, but nothing in combination with the much more advanced version 4.4.2. According to caniuse.com there should be no limitations for this properties on this version.

Does anybody have experience with this issue? Maybe there is a bug in this Android version that I'm not aware of?